# <input type="file"> attribute in IE 11 is not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-11, file-attributes

In IE 11 when you do below coding in HTML

```
<input type="file">
```

Issue :
Browse button and textbox are not aligned properly, there is no space between browse button and textbox.

Is there any way to add space between these two, ie. textbox space browse?

Comment: That's not incorrect layout, it's just a layout Microsoft has chosen. IE11 supports some [pseudo-elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869403%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#pseudo_elements) to style input elements, but nothing for `type="file"` seems to be available.

Comment: use a button instead of a file input, you can style it freely: `<label for=inpFile><button>Upload...</button></label>`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put specific margin/padding to element in.ie explicitly, then with jquery, select the element and add a css classclass, like below>

```
if (window.jquery.browser.msie) {
 window.jquery("input[type="file"]").addClass("{pading:2px}");
}
```

Comment: That's the oddest name of a class I've ever seen ... I doubt if it's even valid? Btw. `.browser` has been obsoleted since jQuery 1.9.

Comment: NO IT is not working . NO space between textbox and browse button